# Issues with manually compiling hydra

Tags: kali-linux-tools

I am trying to install hydra.

First, I typed the command `./configure` and then `make`, but when I typed command `make install` it gave me this error:

```
Now type make install
strip hydra pw-inspector
echo OK > /dev/null && test -x xhydra && strip xhydra || echo OK > /dev/null
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
cp -f hydra-wizard.sh hydra pw-inspector /usr/local/bin && cd /usr/local/bin && chmod 755 hydra-wizard.sh hydra pw-inspector
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/hydra-wizard.sh': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/hydra': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/pw-inspector': Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:86: install] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is actually ubuntu or not, but you need to run `sudo make install`. This will most likely fix your permission denied errors.